# Jquery effect fails when content is inside a asp:repeater

Tags: jquery, repeater

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this.

I'm trying to use the dropdown effect from [this site](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height) and it works fine, But the second that I put it into a asp:repeater it stops working.
It is Click event that dont work when I repeate it( and why repeate??? Im gonna use it to display some groups from my database)

Here is the Code With and WithOut the Repeater.

```
div class="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Test Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
$(function () {
        $(".accordion").accordion({
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    });
```

And with the Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Test Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Do anyone have an idea why it Fails when it goes into the repeater?

Comment: Missing `<` in start of div `<div class="accordion">`  inside `<ItemTemplate>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that i just a simple type error mistake when i pasted it into stackoverflow.

Comment: Post generated HTML when you are using repeater .